# remove linebreaks as string in json

Tags: php, json

I have a little problem in my script

I have json format data like this

```
{"name":"John Wickwicky", "age":31, "city":"Queens, USA", "bio":"linebreaks<br/>waw"}
```

when I want to display json data it uses php with a script like this

```
<?php
$string = '{"name":"John Wickwicky", "age":31, "city":"Queens, USA", "bio":"linebreaks<br/>waw"}';
echo $string;
?>
```

the response is like this

```
{"name":"John Wickwicky", "age":31, "city":"Queens, USA", "bio":"linebreaks
waw"}
```

I have tried by adding the application/json header, and it works, but I want to do json_decode in the $string variable, how can my json_decode succeed and when the data is taken by the text 
 it still appears?

Comment: "How can my json_decode succeed?" If it fails then [json_last_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) will let you know why, but this is valid JSON so it should work just fine. If it doesn't, add the return value of json_last_error to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the linebreak will always appear, I mean that whatever HTML tag is stored in the the variable will remain as it is. And if you look on source of your outpt it will be like this `linebreaks<br/>waw`, although in the browser you see `waw` on the second line. You can try to use [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` accordingly and in that case in your browser you will see `linebreaks<br/>waw` in one line.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function will help you to remove the html tags from the string

**Usage Example**:

```
$string = '{"name":"John Wickwicky", "age":31, "city":"Queens, USA", "bio":"linebreaks<br/>waw"}';
$string = strip_tags($string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: This treats a JSON string as if it were HTML, which is incorrect. strip_tags obviously has no concept of JSON escape sequences and must therefore be called *after* json_decode. Consider what happens if the JSON string is `"\u003Cscript>alert(1)</script>"`.

Comment: You are correct @Peter, The answer is for the given situation